# How to split string in Thymeleaf

Tags: split, thymeleaf

I have imageNames like `wange/25011.jpg|wange/25011-1.jpg` or null, I want to split them to `wange/25011.jpg` and `wange/25011-1.jpg`, or no split if null. I tried code as below, but no work...

```
<td th:if="${brickset.imageNames} != null"  th:each="image : ${#strings.arraySplit(brickset.imageNames, '|')}">
    <a href="#" th:href="${imageBaseUrl + image}">
        <img src="#" th:src="${imageBaseUrl + image}" height="64"/>
    </a>
</td>
```

Comment: I got answer by myself.

Comment: Could your please add an answer to tell us what you did to resolve your issue ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is my own answer:

```
<tbody id="portfolio" class="clear fix">
  <tr th:each="brickset : ${bricksets}" th:alt="${brickset.description}">
    <td>
      <div th:unless="${brickset.imageNames == null}">
        <div th:each="image,status : ${#strings.arraySplit(brickset.imageNames, '|')}">
          <a href="#" th:href="${imageBaseUrl + image}" th:remove="${image} == null ? tag" th:title="${brickset.brand.name}">
            <img src="#" th:src="${imageBaseUrl + image}" height="64" th:remove="${status.index} > 0 ? tag"/>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had a string like below

String times = "Product1#100$@@@Product2#130$";

I wanted to display product name and price in a table raw, for that, I created this. I used this for sending order confirmation emails to the users

[image]

```
<tr th:each="item, count : ${#strings.arraySplit(items, '@@@')}">
   <td width="75%" align="left"
      style="font-family: Open Sans, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 400; line-height: 24px; padding: 15px 10px 5px 10px;"
      th:text="${#strings.arraySplit(item,'#')[0]  + ' ('+ (count.index + 1) +')'}">
   </td>
   <td width="25%" align="left"
      style="font-family: Open Sans, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 400; line-height: 24px; padding: 15px 10px 5px 10px;"
      th:text="${#strings.arraySplit(item,'#')[1]}">
   </td>
</tr>
```