# Thymeleaf strings.arraySplit is not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a similar issue like this question:
[How to split string in Thymeleaf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35669169/how-to-split-string-in-thymeleaf)

I am getting data by using the below code.

```
<tbody th:each="map : ${InsDashboardData}">
   <tr th:each="mapEntry : ${map}">
       <td th:text="${mapEntry.key}"></td>
       <td></td>    
       <td>[[${mapEntry.value}]]</td>   
   </tr>                                
</tbody>
```

[image]

**Requirement:** I need to split the incoming data. For example: I want to split `Master of Computer Application@@@500` into `Master of Computer Application (MCA)` and `500` for respective table headers **Programme Name** and **Intake Capacity**.

I have tried by updating the HTML code to this :

```
 <tbody th:each="map : ${InsDashboardData}">
    <tr th:each="mapEntry : ${map}">
    <td th:with="insData=${mapEntry.key}" th:each="item : ${#strings.arraySplit(${insData}, '@@@')}" th:text="${#strings.arraySplit(item,'#')[0]}"></td>                                            
    <td th:text="${#strings.arraySplit(item,'#')[1]}"></td>
    <td>[[${mapEntry.value}]]</td>  
    </tr>                               
  </tbody>
```

But I'm getting the error given below:

```
Expression [#strings.arraySplit(${insData}, '@@@')] @21: EL1043E: Unexpected token. Expected 'rparen())' but was 'lcurly({)'
```

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Taken ref - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35669169/how-to-split-string-in-thymeleaf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use this line of code to make it work:

- `${#strings.arraySplit(mapEntry.key, '@@@')[0]}` - To get the value before `@@@`.
- `${#strings.arraySplit(mapEntry.key, '@@@')[1]}` - To get the value after `@@@`.

**Controller Code for testing:**

```
@Controller
public class DemoController {

    @GetMapping("/")
    public ModelAndView func() {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("Master of Computer Application@@@500", "316");
        map.put("Bachelor of Computer Application@@@1000", "11");
        modelAndView.setViewName("index");
        modelAndView.addObject("InsDashboardData", map);
        return modelAndView;
    }
}
```

**Updated HTML:**

```
<html xmlns:th="https://thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <style>
        table, th, td {
           border: 1px solid;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Programme Name</th>
        <th>Intake Capacity</th>
        <th>Final Admission</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody th:each="map : ${InsDashboardData}">
    <tr th:each="mapEntry : ${map}">
        <td th:text="${#strings.arraySplit(mapEntry.key, '@@@')[0]}"></td>
        <td th:text="${#strings.arraySplit(mapEntry.key, '@@@')[1]}"></td>
        <td>[[${mapEntry.value}]]</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</html>
```

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The requirement is not entirely clear to me, however, I think I can see the syntactical error here. You do not need to add $ again for inner variable.

> th:each="item : ${#strings.arraySplit(insData, '@@@')}"

Answer (score 1):

Nesting variable expressions  like this: `${... ${...} ...}` is a syntax error.  Once you've started a variable expression, there's no need to surround additional variables with `${...}` expressions.

Here is an example of a working table:

```
<tbody th:each="map : ${InsDashboardData}">
  <tr th:each="entry : ${map}"
      th:with="pieces=${#strings.arraySplit(entry.key, '@@@')}, programName=${pieces[0]}, intakeCapacity=${pieces[1]}, finalAdmission=${entry.value}">
    <td th:text="${programName}" />
    <td th:text="${intakeCapacity}" />
    <td th:text="${finalAdmission}" />
  </tr>
</tbody>
```